# How to run a streaming query over a static dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

When I apply structured streaming to static dataset, the spark engine will get the whole data of static dataset. In this case, what is the meaning of using a stream to process a static data set?

What I expected was that structured streaming was able to get a portion of the entire data set at a time, and then I calculated it on this part of the data set until the entire data set was traversed. Otherwise, using structured streaming and spark SQL to process static data sets is exactly the same.

The reason we use structured streaming to a static dataset is because the static dataset can be large. We want to use structured streaming to prevent the data on the static dataset from being loaded into memory all at once (so that the memory is very stressful). Does this violate the idea of stream processing?

What is the difference between using structured streaming and spark SQL to process static data sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the static dataset can be large.

That is exactly the reason why Spark can help here. That does not say it has to be Structured Streaming though. It's a perfect use case for Spark SQL.

> to prevent the data on the static dataset from being loaded into memory all at once

This is again the reason for Spark, and again has nothing to do with Structured Streaming.